# How to use html format inside Display attribute in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My goal looks like to this snapshot:

[image: 1]

What I've tried:

```
[Display(Name = "To verify, type <i>delete my account</i> below:")]
public bool DeleteAccountConfirmation { get; set; }

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="DeleteAccountConfirmation" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="DeleteAccountConfirmation" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

The text `<i>delete my account</i>` wasn't formatted (as figure).

How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html tags inside DisplayAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212303/html-tags-inside-displayattribute)

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Sorry, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It's essentially similar. Create a custom extension method of `MvcHtmlString` and put the HTML tag atttributes there.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I will try later, thanks!